# Passing variable through url and checking it

Tags: php

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<?
if($mail == "yes"){
echo '<script>alert("hello")</script>';
}
?>
<a href="test.php?mail=yes">Click</a>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Why doesn't the page give me an alert when I click the link? Does PHP recognize the variable I'm trying to pass or do I need to do something else?

Comment: Expecting `$mail` to be populated would be reliant upon [an old removed feature of PHP called `register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php). You need to retrieve `$_GET['mail']` from [the `$_GET` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: the first line of your php references $mail, this is not set anywhere, so it evaluates to an empty string, which doesn't match "yes". you need to set `$mail=$_GET['mail']` before you can check what's in mail. or make your line `if ($_GET['mail'] == "yes")`

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to check for

```
if($_GET['mail'] == 'yes') {
...
}
```

$mail is not set at the time you are checking for it (and never after too in your case). To retrieve values after the question mark in an url

```
http://www.example.com?mail=whatever
```

you need to use $_GET, as this is the superglobal collecting this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($_GET['mail'] == "yes"){
    echo '<script>alert("hello")</script>';
}
```

All your URL parameters are placed in $_GET array, just set parameter name as array key and you will get value passed by URL.

Answer (score -1):

You need to test if the get variable is defined and is not null:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<?php
$mail = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'mail');
if($mail == "yes"){
    echo '<script>alert("hello")</script>';
}
?>
<a href="teste.php?mail=yes">Click</a>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```